# Can I upgrade Windows 10 from Home to Pro version with any key?

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, windows-10-upgrade

I would like to upgrade my Windows 10 Home to Pro, but it is quite expensive, so I looked on some websites. Here, there is two differents versions (https://www.urcdkeys.com/microsoft-windows-10-pro-oem-cd-key-global_1966-20.html & https://www.urcdkeys.com/microsoft-windows-10-pro-retail-cd-key-global.html). On the first one, they are telling me that "You CAN'T upgrade from Home system to Pro system", but not on the second. So it means that I won't be able to use this key for upgrading. But on the second, they aren't telling anything about upgrades. So will I be able to upgrade Windows 10 from Home to Pro version with the key on the second link?

Comment: There is a difference between OEM and Retail keys.  That website is not selling authorized keys.  Those are gray market keys.  The absence of the warning doesn’t mean it doesn’t apply.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Home is OEM (even from System Builders). So each Windows 10 Home license is separate.

To upgrade to Windows 10 Pro, you need to purchase the Pro Upgrade Key from Microsoft. I do not recommend third party sites for this.

You cannot use the same key on the other system and must purchase a second Pro key.